# how to parse following json in php

Tags: php, foreach, json

how to parse following json in php

```
[
 { "user":"John", "age":22, "country":"United States" },
 { "user":"Will", "age":27, "country":"United Kingdom" },
 { "user":"Abiel", "age":19, "country":"Mexico" },
 { "user":"Rick", "age":34, "country":"Panama" },
 { "user":"Susan", "age":23, "country":"Germany" },
 { "user":"Amy", "age":43, "country":"France" }
]
```

i use the following code for this but it didnt work

```
$jsonData = file_get_contents("http://localhost/attendance1/a.json");
$phpArray = json_decode($jsonData, true);
echo $phpArray;
foreach ($phpArray as $key => $value) {
    echo "<h2>$key</h2>";
    foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
        echo "$k | $v <br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not valid JSON.

Comment: An array should be surrounded with `[ ... ]`, not `{ ... }`.

Comment: That is not a valid JSON string.

Comment: With the corrected JSON, your script works for me.

Comment: You should try and not update your original post with fixed code, that way your question still makes sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to change your json primary item to array (instead object) using [ ] instead { }.

```
[
 { "user":"John", "age":22, "country":"United States" },
 { "user":"Will", "age":27, "country":"United Kingdom" },
 { "user":"Abiel", "age":19, "country":"Mexico" },
 { "user":"Rick", "age":34, "country":"Panama" },
 { "user":"Susan", "age":23, "country":"Germany" },
 { "user":"Amy", "age":43, "country":"France" }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

it's not a valid JSON Format, try this:

```
[
 { "user":"John", "age":22, "country":"United States" },
 { "user":"Will", "age":27, "country":"United Kingdom" },
 { "user":"Abiel", "age":19, "country":"Mexico" },
 { "user":"Rick", "age":34, "country":"Panama" },
 { "user":"Susan", "age":23, "country":"Germany" },
 { "user":"Amy", "age":43, "country":"France" }
]
```

(look at square brackets)

"[]" brackets indicates a LIST, while "{}" indicates an object.
The difference between them is that objects contains "key":"value" pairs, while lists return items without a key

Answer (score 0):

```
[
 { "user":"John", "age":22, "country":"United States" },
 { "user":"Will", "age":27, "country":"United Kingdom" },
 { "user":"Abiel", "age":19, "country":"Mexico" },
 { "user":"Rick", "age":34, "country":"Panama" },
 { "user":"Susan", "age":23, "country":"Germany" },
 { "user":"Amy", "age":43, "country":"France" }
]
```

the format is like
an array

```
$array = [3,5,7,4]
```

which prints like

```
Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 5 [2] => 7 [3] => 4 )
```

and elements accessed a `$array{index}` 
In the same way using loop you should access the elements and then you can use the function json_decode.

```
$object = json_decode($element_of_array)
```

which returns an object using that object you can access data from json element.

```
$object->user
$object->age
```

hope this would be helpful for you,
Good Luck!